# Emacs 27 looses code blocks while tangling file

Tags: emacs, org-mode, literate-programming

Emacs 25 and earlier versions tangle my emacs config
https://github.com/zahardzhan/well-tuned-emacs/blob/master/README.org
perfectly well, but Emacs 27 looses some code blocks for unknown reason. What is wrong with the latest org-mode? Does it change something about tangling?

Answer (score 1):

Solved https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51845/9911 use `:noweb-ref` instead of `#+name:`